# Updating MySQl database from JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I coded a form to update login details of a user. But updating is not successful.

I'm new to JSP so help me to update data of the user to the MySQL database by clicking save button.

My code is shown below;

```
<%
String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/pmsdb";
String USERNAME = "dbuser";
String PASSWORD = "dbpassword";

Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
ResultSet rs =null;

if(request.getParameter("submit")!=null){
    String cuser=request.getParameter("currentusername"); 
    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
    String cpwd = request.getParameter("confirmpasword");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
     String sql = "UPDATE supplierinfo SET username='"+user+"', password='"+pwd+"' WHERE username='"+cuser+"' ";

     if(cuser!=null && user!=null && pwd!=null && cpwd!=null  ){
     pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     pst.execute(); 
     }else{
     %>
     <script language="JavaScript">
         alert("Fill all fields and try again")
     </script>
     <%
     }
}
    %>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 settingbox">
    <div class="panel panel-login">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login Details</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" id="register-form-link">General Details</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form id="login-form" action="" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="currentusername" id="currentusername" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Username" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="New Username" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm New Password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Save">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: did you get any exception?, if so paste it here

Comment: no exceptions but not updating data @Srinu

Comment: you should print out your update sql and check it use database tool.

Comment: @hinata print `sql` and try running it manually in database, your code seems fine. check `cuser` exists or not in your database, if exists  check is there any spaces before or after `cuser`.

Comment: as @Srinu indicates you should check if the `cuser` exists in db if not, the thing you are looking for is `INSERT INTO` as your query, 'cause you need a row at first to update it.

Comment: error is when I fill all Fields and try to update shows the JavaScript alert to fill all fields:( @Srinu  how can I fix it.. I can't see any errors in my if else code :( by the way I have the row in database:)

Comment: @mastah please check the comment above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading the data from the `form`, you have used `confirmpasword` instead of `confirmpassword`.

change the following

```
 String cpwd = request.getParameter("confirmpasword");
```

to

```
String cpwd = request.getParameter("confirmpassword");
```

And one more thing is when a form filed is submitted, `null` will sent for `textbox` fileds.

change your `if` condition to the following, it'll check for null and as well as `empty sting`.

```
if((cuser!=null &&cuser.length()>0) 
 && (user!=null &&user.length()>0)  
 && (pwd!=null && pwd.length()>0)
 && cpwd!=null && cpwd.length()>0) ) {
 // statements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line:

```
String cpwd = request.getParameter("confirmpasword");
```

And the request appends:

```
<input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="password"...
```

Java controller tries to get null parameter. (You are missing a `s` char in `getParameter` parameter)

Consider validating form fields both for null and empty situation using simple method like:

```
public boolean isSet(String s){
    if(s==null || "".equals(s)) return false; //String not set
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thats funny on stackoverflow, i answered before accepted answer poster giving very similar answer, so similar that this addidional validation check was just a remake of my function